# How can I resolve runtime error 3075 in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have problem running this code. It gives me Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

```
Function SearchCriteria()

Dim class,StateProvince,strAcademicYear As As String 
Dim task, strCriteria As String 

If isNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboClass) Then
   Class = "[Class] LIKE '*' "
Else
   Class = [Class] = " & Forms!frmStudentList!cboClass
End If
If isNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboStateProvince) Then
   StateProvince = "[StateProvince] LIKE '*' "
Else
   StateProvince = [StateProvince] = " & 
Forms!frmStudentList!cboStateProvince
End If
If isNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboAcademicYear) Then
   StrAcademicYear = "[AcademicYear] LIKE '*' "
Else
   StrAcademicYear = [AcademicYear] = '" & 

Forms!frmStudentList!cboAcademicYear & "'"
End If
strCriteria = Class & "AND" & StateProvince & "AND" & StrAcademicYear
task = "SELECT * FROM QryStudentSearch WHERE & Criteria
Forms!frmStudentList.RecordSource = task
Forms!frmStudentList.Requery

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with this piece of code.

- Firstly, most of your variables aren't explicitly declared as being of a type, so default to being `Variant`.
- Next, Class is a reserved word in Access, and will probably cause you problems.
- If a control has no choice made, you are using `LIKE '*'` to select data. There is no need to do this, as by applying no filter means that all records will be returned anyway.
- As it doesn't return a value, you can create this as a `Sub` rather than a `Function`.
- The main problem is with how you are concatenating the different parts together.

I would rewrite the code as:

```
Sub sSearch()
    Dim strSearch As String
    If Not IsNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboClass) Then
        strSearch = strSearch & " AND [Class]='" & Forms!frmStudentList!cboClass & "' "
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboStateProvince) Then
        strSearch = strSearch & " AND [StateProvince]='" & Forms!frmStudentList!cboStateProvince & "' "
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Forms!frmStudentList!cboAcademicYear) Then
        strSearch = strSearch & " AND [AcademicYear]='" & Forms!frmStudentList!cboAcademicYear & "' "
    End If
    If Left(strSearch, 4) = " AND" Then
        strSearch = "WHERE " & Mid(strSearch, 6)
    End If
    strSearch = "SELECT * FROM qryStudentSearch " & strSearch
    Forms!frmStudentList.RecordSource = strSearch
    Forms!frmStudentList.Requery
End Sub
```

In each case, I am assuming that the bound column of each combo box is text, hence the need to use single quotes around the data. If the bound column is numeric, then the single quotes can be removed.

Regards,